# ngModel doesn't work in the custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I knew definitely it is problem I didn't understand the scope of AngularJs well. I had to committed it is hard for me. So I post a example here, Hope someone help me to get it more clear. Thanks.

**Html Part**

```
<test-Area ng-model="testModel.text"></test-Area>
<input type="text" ng-model="testModel.text"></input>
<textarea ng-model="testModel.text"></textarea>
```

**JS Part**

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $log) {
    $scope.testModel={text:"123"};
})

app.directive('testArea',function() {
    var textareaInputDir = {};
    textareaInputDir.restrict="E";
    textareaInputDir.replace="true";
    textareaInputDir.template="<div><textarea ></textarea><label><small></small><span >*</span></label></div>";
    textareaInputDir.require="ngModel";
    textareaInputDir.link=function (scope, jqElement, attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
        scope.backgroundValue={text:''};
        ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
            jqElement.find('textarea').text(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            scope.backgroundValue.text=ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
        }
        //get the textarea element
        var txtAreaElement = jqElement.find('textarea');
        //listen for the change event

        txtAreaElement.bind('keyup', function(){
            if (scope.$$phase) return;
            scope.$apply(function () {
                var bgVal=angular.isString(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) ? ngModelCtrl.$viewValue : '';
                scope.backgroundValue.text=bgVal;
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(bgVal);
            });

        });
        scope.$watch('backgroundValue.text',function()
        {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.backgroundValue.text)
        });
    };
    return textareaInputDir;
});
```

Please review what I had done so far in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/5Qmn8/2/).

I was trying to implement a two ways binding for my directive `testArea` and others. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my directive?

**Updated**

I changed the code a little bit. but still have problem. if I changed the value of text area. the 2 ways binding will be lost...

```
txtAreaElement.bind('keyup', function(){
            if (scope.$$phase) return;
            scope.$apply(function () {
                var txtAreaElement = jqElement.find('textarea');        
                var bgVal=txtAreaElement[0].value;
                scope.backgroundValue.text=bgVal;
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(bgVal);

            });

        });
```

Comment: Could you posts relevant parts from your fiddle in your post?

Comment: @pixelbits Sorry to forget to post code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found if I want to apply **bi-directional binding**. It doesn't need to use `NgModelController`. according to [this tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html).

Please review below.

**HTML**

```
<test-Area ng-model="testModel.text"></test-Area>
```

**js**

```
app.directive('testArea',function() {
    var textareaInputDir = {};
    textareaInputDir.restrict="E";
    textareaInputDir.replace="true";
    textareaInputDir.scope={ngModel:'='};
    textareaInputDir.template="<div><textarea ng-model='ngModel'></textarea><label><small></small><span >*</span></label></div>";

    return textareaInputDir;
});
```

If there is something wrong. please kindly correct me .thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must set up `ng-model` not on you directeve, you need to set it on `textarea` element

[check example](http://jsfiddle.net/manar007/5Qmn8/6/)

In your way you are applying to directive template element which is starting with `<div>`.

Comment: No. doing so will be against the oop design of custom directive. doesn't it ?

Comment: your question is 
"I was trying a two ways binding for my directive testArea and others. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my directive?"
I described whats your mistake, and now what your concern I didnt understand ?

Comment: because the value of ng-model is not hard-code. it can be changed.

Comment: In that case you can pass your vars into directive scope like a 
<test-Area text="testModel.text"></test-Area> and then in directive put this on ng-model, making sense ?

Comment: I thought about another way, you can do like this http://jsfiddle.net/manar007/5Qmn8/8/ , the first element is the text are and the ng-model applying on it, if you want to have custom template for textarea for example <div> <another element> <textarea></textarea> ..... blah blah, then you can use ng-transclude, that will be more elegant way https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: you changed the root element to textarea. so the ng-model will impact on it directly. it doesn't make sense to implement a custom directive like this. this is not what i expected. thanks.

Comment: thats why im saying if you want to wrap it in custom container, you should use ng transclude :)

Comment: could you help to add ng transclude to fiddle to make it work please?thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manar007/5Qmn8/12/
In this case it making sens to use directive for textarea if you want to do event listeing on that textarea or for example turn on watchers etc.

Comment: try to use this template html `<div><textarea ></textarea><label><small></small><span >*</span></label></div>`. you sample will not work.

Comment: So..If I want to use it . I have to write like this `<panel><test-Area >.....</test-Area></panel>`. hm..It looks verbose. Any better solution?

Comment: Hi Narek, I found a way to make it. Please review it. thanks.

Comment: In this case why you need ng-model ? you can set for instance `blah="foo" ` , why you especial need ng-model :)

Comment: :) I know I can use other names to replace of `ng-model`. But name convention for the reusable directive is a careful job. it is better make a sensible and meaningful name for attribute or directive name. I believe everyone who use angular would understand better what does `ng-model` means than others. it is more common sense than others. right?

Comment: Yes its your choice, you know what will be better :)