# providing ngModel into custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a custom AngularJS directive that uses input tag with some more features.

***index.html***

`sabel-input-directive ng-model="number" label="number" type='number' min="3" max="10" required="false" sabel-input-directive`

I want to provide the `ng-model` attribute that I can use it as regular.

This custom tag contain just one tag of input
`<input name='myInput'>`

I tried to pass in a string in directive attributes and to give it in the inner tag like so:

`input name='myInput' ng-model='{{theModel}}'` but it didn't work.

I know that I have to `"require: ngModel"`

but I don't know how to do this :( and the important thing that I want to specify the model name from the attributes of the custom directive :)

so pls Help, because this tag will help a lot I guess!
and thanks :)

Comment: here is what I searched for :) :) and it's working!! oh GOD
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691403/ngmodel-doesnt-work-in-the-custom-directive

Answer (score 0):

You dont wrap `themodel` in mustaches in `ng-model` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed good article about scope in directives.
[Link to article.](https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/)

Angular controller from we will grab the ng-model and directive with own scope

```
angular.controller("ctr", function($scope){
  $scope.model = {
    name: "Hi"
  };
});

angular.directive("example", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<input type='text' ng-model='model'>",
    scope: {
      model: "="
    },
});
```

Now html code

```
<div ng-controller="ctr">
  <example data-model="model"></example>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to create for every tag a variable in the scope, I want it to be dynamically. like just writting:

<my-directive ng-model='myVar'></my-directive>

without creating any thing in the Ctrl, like we use ng-model often

Comment: I have an example that close what I want And using those methods:

ngModel.$parsers
ngModel.$setValidity
ngModel.$modelValue